# Android Robolectric packages not found. Unknown packaging: apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, robolectric

Hi I'm trying to use the maven android plugin and robolectric to get tests working. Right now I just have one test class which is under src/test.... I've followed the instructions here to try and get this working: http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/maven-quick-start.html

UPDATED: I have followed the advice of those who posted to me here and here is my latest Pom.xml and compile output.

Here is my Pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mozilla.android.sync</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-sync</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>sync</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <!-- try 4.10 once we get this working -->
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <!--<pluginManagement>-->
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- version 2.3 defaults to java 1.5, so no further configuration needed-->
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <!--
            <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>-->
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-alpha-13</version>
            <configuration>
            <sdk>
                <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                <platform>10</platform>
            </sdk>
            <emulator>
                <!-- the name of the avd device to use for starting the emulator -->
                <avd>android-14</avd>
            </emulator>
            <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--</pluginManagement>-->
    </build>
   </project>
```

Output of mvn clean install:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sync 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ android-sync ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-13:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ android-sync ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] /Users/jason/dev/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools/aapt [package, -m, -J, /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/target/generated-sources/r, -M, /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/res, --auto-add-overlay, -I, /Users/jason/dev/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-10/android.jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ android-sync ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ android-sync ---
[INFO] Compiling 21 source files to /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[6,33] package com.xtremelabs.robolectric does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[7,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[8,23] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[10,26] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[10,0] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[11,23] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[11,0] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[13,1] cannot find symbol
symbol: class RunWith
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[16,5] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Test
location: class org.mozilla.android.sync.test.MyActivityTest
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[19,28] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method equalTo(java.lang.String)
location: class org.mozilla.android.sync.test.MyActivityTest
[INFO] 10 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.019s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 12 13:02:42 PST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project android-sync: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[6,33] package com.xtremelabs.robolectric does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[7,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[8,23] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[10,26] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[10,0] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[11,23] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[11,0] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[13,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[16,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Test
[ERROR] location: class org.mozilla.android.sync.test.MyActivityTest
[ERROR] /Users/jason/dev/work/android-sync/src/test/java/org/mozilla/android/sync/test/MyActivityTest.java:[19,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method equalTo(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: class org.mozilla.android.sync.test.MyActivityTest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did make sure that all dependencies were listed before the android dependencies

Actually the order of dependencies does matter, in the link your provided yourself, see the important comments in the sample pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Make sure this is below the android dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>X.X.X</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

From my own experiences, I think this library is still in a development stage, their API is not stable and change quite a lot between different version, code working in a old version for example 0.9.4 may not working in 1.0-XX or later. try download/use the latest versrion from there [sonatype repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~robolectric)

Comment: That may be true...but my current problem is now having to do with maven recognizing that the package type of "apk" as mentioned above. I can comment out the dependencies right now and still have this issue with it not knowing how to build an apk. You can see in the edit to my post that this is my current issue: Unknown packaging: apk @ line 7, column 13

Comment: Try downgrade android-maven-plugin api level <platform>10</platform>, not sure, worth to try. Or attach the detailed error stack trace.

Comment: So the plugins needed to beoutside of <pluginManagement> ...but now I am back to my original problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> from your pom.xml, by define this, you are telling maven-compiler-plugin looking for source for compiling only in src folder, all java files in test folder are ignored.

Comment: But my tests are under src as well. My directory structure has a src folder with "main" and "tests" within it.

Comment: Your pom works for me once I remove the sourceDirectory, just try it.

Comment: However...your suggestion seems to be working. Thanks! This has ended a long string of hours of frustration :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have that problem due to the order of the test dependency in the pom file. Move the junit one to be the last one or at least behind the robolectric one. That should fix it.

Check out the working [robolectric sample app](https://github.com/mosabua/RobolectricSample/blob/androidmaven/pom.xml) for more comparison.

Comment: That didn't seem to help at all. However, when i added the tags <pluginManagement> which enclose the <plugins> section, that seemed to help. However now I am getting a new error: Unknown packaging: apk @ line 7, column 13

Comment: you still have to reference the android maven plugin in the build / plugins section as well if you add the others to plugin mgt. Just try adopting the pom from the sample. It works.

Comment: I've tried adopting the format and reposted my file above. Do you see anything that I could still be missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I was having the same problems too. For what it's worth, I wasn't using maven or gradle, here's how I fixed this issue.

In your Test class:

1. Make sure the Roboelectric library is first in the list of dependencies (In IntelliJ, click on your project in the Navigation Pane and hit <kbd>F4</kbd>).
2. `import org.junit.runner.RunWith;` <- The RunWith annotation is actually part of JUnit.
3. `import org.roboelectric.RoboeletricTestRunner;`

I hope this helps!